# MS Access two-listbox control

Tags: vba, ms-access

What is this side-by-side listbox control called? Can it be used in MS Access 2010, or do I have to make it from scratch? (this question has nothing to do with the query wizard--I am trying to see if I can make a control like the listboxes for my application)

[image: side-by-side list boxes]

Comment: the `from scratch` is pretty much the way to go. you can look online for a ready control. but it is really simple to do your own ( from scratch )

Comment: @mehow resubmit your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the from `scratch` is pretty much the way to go. I guess you could look around for a ready control, but I haven't been able to find one within 10-15 minutes of searching. It is really simple to do your own. If you follow these articles you will easily achieve what you want with under 30 minutes

[Youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbM3vPbNibg) - this uses the worksheet forms but you can easily adapt it to work on a userform - the logic remains the same.

[Web Tutorial](http://www.contextures.com/excelvbalistboxmove.html) - that seems to be a nice tutorial with lots of screenshots and good description of the steps.